# iOS // displaying lots of large (fullscreen) remote images

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I'm experiencing problems (app crashes) when navigating in an app that uses lots of remote image (a hundred total, more or less)s

Using SDWebImage, [what's described here by many](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/538) is what happens (the memory usages' getting huge)

What would be a better tool/pod to recommend ?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @jurgemaister I've edited

Comment: R u displaying your on any TableView or CollectionView??? means at the time of navigation the request are in process but delegate get nil. might be that is the reason app going to be crashes

Comment: Don't keep all of them in memory? If you have to display 100+ images at a time, then reduce the size of them. They'll be like 20x20 images anyway.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke or https://github.com/jaminguy/JGAFImageCache I've heard Haneke is very good and easy to use. I myself haven't used it too much, so can't say anything.

Comment: They are not displayed at once; meant a hundred by the amount used through different views (and as it makes the memory grows)

Comment: If it's making the memory grow, you're doing it wrong. When switching screens, the images on the previous screen should be deallocated.

Comment: @sonu_patel nope; theyre displayed in uiviews. Any downfall to do so ?

Comment: @lord zsolt yep for sure there some i might do wrong. But if you read through the link provided; i wonder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke).

Here's a list of it's features:

- First-level memory cache using NSCache.
- Second-level LRU disk cache using the file system.
- Zero-config UIImageView category to use the cache, optimized for UITableView and UICollectionView cell reuse.
- Asynchronous and synchronous image retrieval.
- Background image resizing and file reading.
- Image decompression.
- Custom image transformations before and after resizing.
- Thread-safe.
- **Automatic cache eviction on memory warnings or disk capacity reached.**
- Preloading images from the disk cache into memory on startup.

Comment: Thanks! i'll have a look at it